# How to have different window tiling options?

Tags: window, resize

I am actually talking about options like:

> 1st window: 1/3 of screen
> 2nd window: 2/3 of screen

> 1st window: 1/2 of screen
> 2nd window: 1/2 of screen

> 1st window: 2/3 of screen
> 2nd window: 1/3 of screen

and so on ...

actually like Macos X . with keybord shortcuts ...

Comment: You're looking for a "tiling window manager" - there are many; Gnome is not one by default, but there are extensions available, as described in @vanadium's answer.
i3wm is *extremely* good for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to tiling. Tiling options in default Ubuntu are very limited. You can only tile left and right half of the screen.

With an extension, [WinTile: Windows 10 window tiling for GNOME by Fmstrat](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1723/wintile-windows-10-window-tiling-for-gnome/), you can expand tiling capabilities. The extension can also be set to work with three (and four) vertical colums, so you could tile 1/3 of the screen.

To allow for 2/3 tiling, you must change some options in the Wintile extension:

- Set "Number of columns" to 3
- Uncheck "Use true maximizing of windows"
- Uncheck "Enable preview and snapping when dragging windows

With these settings, a layout like

> 1st window: 1/3 of screen 2nd window: 2/3 of screen"

is actually possible.

- Hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to tile the first window 1/3 of the screen
- Select the second window, then maximize with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> then hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to tile it in the right 2/3.

Comment: This extension claims it is incompatible with the latest version of Ubuntu (Impish Indri).